# Show that solution of a Cauchy problem is not globally defined

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, cauchy-problem

Hi everyone: I need a check on the following exercise

> \begin{cases} u'(t)=\sin(t)^2 - u(t)^2 \\ u(0)=-1\end{cases}
>
> Show that the maximal solution $u:[\alpha,\beta] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\beta < \infty$

---

First of all, the problem is well posed: the r.h.s. of the ODE is smooth and therefore we can infer there exists a unique local solution. Then, I note immediately that $$\sin(t)^2-u^2(t) > - u^2(t)$$ for all the $t$'s for which the solution is defined

Hence $$u'>-u^2$$ and integrating from $0$ to $t$ I obtain $$\frac{1}{u(t)} + 1 < t$$ and then $$u(t) > \frac{1}{t-1}$$ again for all $t$'s such that the solution is defined. But the r.h.s explodes as $t \rightarrow 1^{-}$ and therefore we can say that the $$\beta<1$$ is necessary for the solution norm not to explode

---

This seems to be confirmed also numerically. **Is everything okay**?

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  As $t \to 1-$, $1/(t-1) \to -\infty$.  So all you have shown is that $\lim_{t\to 1-} u(t) > -\infty$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith But if I take the modulus, I have shown that the norm explodes, right?

Comment: No.  $u(t)$ will be negative.  You cannot say $x<y$ implies $|x| < |y|$ unless you know $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Rewrite the equation in terms of $v = -u$.  So $v'(t) = v(t)^2 - \sin^2(t)$ and $v(0) = 1$.

Comment: Now you can see that $v$ tries to explode, but it just doesn't go fast enough to explode before $\beta = 1$.

Comment: Oh right,so indeed I can repeat all the steps above, using $v'>v^2$, integrate from $0$ to $t$ and see that $|v(t)|> \frac{1}{1-t}$ and therefore it has to be $\beta <1$, right? @StephenMontgomery-Smith

Comment: No.  Because the $-\sin^2(t)$ goes the wrong way.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith right, so what I have to analyze is  $v'<v^2$, but this time $v$ is positive,

Comment: But if you analyse just that, you won't get the blow up.  For example, $v(t) = 1$ satisfies $v' < v^2$.

Comment: Okay, so I got $v(t)>\frac{1}{t+1}$ Now I know that $v(t)=-u(t)$, but this doesn't seem to help @StephenMontgomery-Smith

Comment: How did you get that?  You should have got $v(t) < \frac1{1-t}$ for $0 \le t < 1$.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is much more subtle than the work you showed here.  You need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: Yes sure, it was a typo. Btw, I don't know honestly how to move now. Could you give me a hint? @StephenMontgomery-Smith

Comment: Find an $\epsilon$ such that $v(\epsilon) > 1$.  Then use $v' > v^2 - 1$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith from $v'>v^2 -1 $ I obtain  $v(t)>1$, which implies $u(t)>-1$

Comment: First, if $v > 1$, this implies $u < -1$.  Secondly, try integrating $\int \frac{dv}{1-v^2}$.

Comment: @andereBen : You already know $u(0) = -1$ and $u'(0) = -1$, so "$u(t) > -1$" is utterly hopeless...

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith by integration, I find $\frac{1}{2} \Bigl( \log(1+v) - \log(1-v) \Bigr)$, but the sign in the denominator seems changed

Comment: I think you meant $\tfrac12(\log(v+1)-\log(v-1))$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith So, summarizing, I have $$\frac{1}{2} \Bigl( \log(1+v(t)) - \log(v(t)-1) \Bigr) > 1 $$ I see that for $v=1$ I have problems, but as you wrote,I need to think about this for a while

Comment: I think you need to step away from stack exchange, and think long and hard about this prolem.

Answer (score 1):

At $t=0$ the right side is negative. It is easy to observe, perhaps harder to formulate, that this implies that at no point the right side can become positive, $u$ is continuously falling and thus always smaller than $-1$. Then for $t\in[0,1]$
$$
u'(t)=\sin^2t-u(t)^2\le t^2-1\implies u(t)\le -1-t+\frac{t^3}3=v(t).
$$
so the solution moves decidedly away from the level $-1$ downward and
$$
u(1)\le-\frac53.
$$

Now use $\sin^2t\le 1\le -u(t)$, $u(t)^{-1}+1\ge0$ to derive a simple upper bound for the solution for $t\ge 1$,
$$
u'\le -u-u^2\implies (u^{-1}+1)'=-u^{-2}u'\ge u^{-1}+1
\\~\\
\implies
u(t)^{-1}+1\ge (u(h)^{-1}+1)e^{t-h}
$$
So in the numerically simple case $h=1$ one gets for $t\ge1$
$$
u(t)^{-1}+1\ge\frac25e^{t-1}
\iff 
u(t)\le-\frac{5}{5-2e^{t-1}}
$$
This upper bound diverges to $-\infty$ at $t=1+\ln\frac52$, thus forces the solution to diverge in this direction at some time before that.

This is a rather large bound, as the numerical solution diverges shortly after $t=1$, closely following the lower bound $-\frac1{1-t}$ discussed in the question.